# How can i install Mongodb on 32 bit ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb

Is there any possible for installation of mongodb on ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Since MongoDB is in the standard repositories, please update your question stating exactly what you tried and where you got stuck in the installation process. Moreover, specify what Ubuntu version you have.

Answer (score 5):

Try running **ALL** the commands below, one by one

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

<sub>[Source](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)</sub>

Taken from https://serverfault.com/a/728145/155817:

> For installation on 32 bit OS,  based on mongdodb [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/) you can try to install the tarball installation. That is (taken from the docs):
>
> 1. download the binary files [here](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads) or using

```
`curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.6.tgz`
```

> 2. extract the files
>
>    `tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.6.tgz`
> 3. copy extracted files
>
>    ```
>    mkdir -p mongodb
>    cp -R -n mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.6/ mongodb
>    ```
> 4. add it to PATH
>
>    ```
>    #example in ~/.bashrc
>    export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH
>    ```
>
> **note** as noted in mongodb using this method will have some limitation
>
> "This 32-bit legacy distribution does not include SSL encryption and
>   is limited to around 2GB of data. In general you should use the 64 bit
>   builds."
>
> but in the end it is up to you.

Comment: what;s the error

Comment: were all the commands above it successfully executed ?

Comment: yes..and  but   the end of update command shows a warning as     follows:      W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/wily/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: I have made some updates to answer, try following the 32 bit installation process, it might help you. Coz mongodb has stopped support for 32 bit OS and that's why there is nothing is repositories of 32 bit OS.

Comment: Ok done...Nandri Mr.Sharma.

Comment: I want show u some screen shots.

Comment: Should I edit in  '/etc/apt/sources.list'.?