# Install Mongodb manually on 32bit system

Tags: ubuntu-mate, mongodb

I followed the instructions here `https://askubuntu.com/questions/772181/how-can-i-install-mongodb-on-32-bit-ubuntu` 
to install mongodb-org 3.0 on a 32 bit system.

However, when I run `mongo --version` I get:

```
bash: /usr/bin/mongo: Not a directory
```

Why is it looking in /usr/bin/mongo instead of calling it from PATH?  How can I get this to work?

Comment: Did you source the `.bashrc` file after setting it up?

Comment: Please either close and open a new terminal, or run `source ~/.bashrc` then try again

Comment: What is the purpose of running source ~/.bashrc?  I'm asking in the context of this question. I ran it an it did not change anything.  I have added other symbolic links that worked fine without running the snippet you suggest.

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` is used to reload your `.bashrc` file so any changes will be picked up! Can you added that as an answer, i.e. the snippet you added.

Comment: Ok. I see, but where is the best place to modify $PATH so it is persisted and available from everywhere.  For example, the suggestion here is to use ~/.bashrc, but why not in /etc/profile?

Comment: By the way it is working now by adding the path to ~/.bashrc and then sourcing it.  I was just curious about where the best place is to add to PATH and the pros and cons. Thanks.

Comment: It depends if its just you then that's ok but if you want other to access it then place that in `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

To summarize based on the comments and pointers provided, the solution was to add `export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH` to my `~/.bashrc` file and then source it: `source ~/.bashrc`